# Segmentation Fault Due to Lack of Command Line Argument (argv[1])

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

This segment of code is meant to check if a user has entered only one numeric command-line argument, and return an error code of "1" if this is not the case. I have the code set up so that it first checks if argc is anything other than 2. Unfortunately, I am still receiving Segmentation Faults if no command line argument is entered, and I'm not sure why this code doesn't catch a null amount of command line arguments.

I tried moving the "if (argc !=2)" formula above the entire "for" statement to try and catch the command line argument issue right from the beginning, but I received the same result.

My question is, why am I receiving a Segmentation Fault when no command line argument is provided, and what am I missing to ensure the program doesn't Seg Fault with no command line argument?

Due to course policy, I will only be providing the segment of code in question.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // add'l variables //
    int k = atoi(argv[1]);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            printf("Please enter only 1 command-line argument.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
// add'l code //
```

[Error as shown in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGZ5e.png)

Comment: The problem occurs in the line `int k = atoi(argv[1])`, do the `argc` check before that.

Comment: You're receiving a segmentation fault because you are trying to access something that does not exist.You do provide at least one command line argument (executable), though you need at least 2 for your code to run.

Answer (score 0):

You must first check the `argc` before using the `argv[1]`, because `argv[1]` may not have a valid pointer if `argc < 2`. A corrected version of your code could be like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Please enter only 1 command-line argument.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (isdigit(argv[1][i]))
               ++i;
    if (argv[1][i] != '\0') {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```